# Find index of value in associative array in php?

Tags: php, loops

If you have any array $p that you populated in a loop like so:

```
$p[] = array( "id"=>$id, "Name"=>$name);
```

What's the fastest way to search for John in the Name key, and if found, return the $p index? Is there a way other than looping through $p?

I have up to 5000 names to find in $p, and $p can also potentially contain 5000 rows. Currently I loop through $p looking for each name, and if found, parse it (and add it to another array), splice the row out of $p, and break 1, ready to start searching for the next of the 5000 names.

I was wondering if there if a faster way to get the index rather than looping through $p eg an isset type way?

Thanks for taking a look guys.

Comment: no other way. you have to loop. PHP internally doesn't maintain any hashmap or similar for values; just for keys. (through you could create an extra array which is of type `$q[$p[$key]] = $key;`)

Comment: OMG if you can't use database for manipulating so big data, so no matter anything else

Comment: The only way is to create another associative array with all the names  and an index (or array with indexes if names aren't unqiue) to each location of a name in $p, which you should maintain alongside $p.

Comment: @GeorgePHP FYI, database is not the only data source. :)

Comment: yes it's not only data source but you can use it in another ways too:P even for temp usage

Comment: instead of storing an array of arrays how about just storing a simple list() `http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php`  should do exactly what you want and be a little easier to get the databack

Comment: @GeorgePHP If data comes from WS, you save it to temporary db and then run query against it? Don't you think this is overkill (not to say anything about performance)?

Comment: @leri memory tables or tmptables are pretty much as fast as just doing it all in ram but still if the source is out side of a DB initially I still wouldn't bother. although there's alot to be said for using db tables especially on larger systems. but 5k records is only small so doing it all in ram is more than fast enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so as I see this problem, you have unique ids, but the names may not be unique.

You could initialize the array as:

```
array($id=>$name);
```

And your searches can be like:

```
array_search($name,$arr);
```

This will work very well as native method of finding a needle in a haystack will have a better implementation than your own implementation.

e.g.

```
$id = 2;
$name= 'Sunny';
$arr = array($id=>$name);
echo array_search($name,$arr);
```

**Echoes 2**

The major advantage in this method would be code readability.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are going to need to perform many of these types of search within the same request then you can create an index array from them. This will loop through the array once per index you need to create.

```
$piName = array();
foreach ($p as $k=>$v)
{
  $piName[$v['Name']] = $k;
}
```

If you only need to perform one or two searches per page then consider moving the array into an external database, and creating the index there.

Comment: While it looks good for finding first entry (that will be the corresponding key, of course) - it will not fit OP's request if he need to hold multiple entries in source array with same `Name` field

Comment: It will find the *last* entry actually, which differs from the OP's current algorithm (which finds the first).

Comment: Ah, yes, got that. My point was - if reconstruct source array in this way, obviously, this may be a reason of loosing multiple values. So this structure can not be used _instead_ of original, but can be used _with_ it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = 0;
$search_for = 'John';
$result = array_reduce($p, function($r, $v) use (&$index, $search_for) {
  if($v['Name'] == $search_for) {
    $r[] = $index;
  }
  ++$index;
  return $r;
});
```

$result will contain all the indices of elements in $p where the element with key `Name` had the value `John`. (This of course only works for an array that is indexed numerically beginning with 0 and has no “holes” in the index.)

---

Edit: Possibly even easier to just use `array_filter`, but that will not return the indices only, but all array element where `Name` equals `John` – but indices will be preserved:

```
$result2 = array_filter($p, function($elem) {
  return $elem["Name"] == "John" ? true : false;
});
var_dump($result2);
```

What suits your needs better, resp. which one is maybe faster, is for you to figure out.